# Changing a links href and text on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I have three buttons each display their own content when clicked. But what I want to happen is the active links text to change to about us and the href to change too. My problem is that I can get the text to change but it doesn't change back when I click another link, and I don't know how to make this happen. Another problem is that as soon as I click it the first time href changes and I need it to change when it is clicked the second time not the first time. Hopefully all that makes sense.

https://codepen.io/Reece_Dev/pen/gWdEoJ

```js
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('.link').on('click', function()
    {
        $('.pageContainer').addClass('hide');
        $('#'+ $(this).data('target')).removeClass('hide');
        
        if($(this).on('click')){
            $(this).attr("href", "https://www.google.com");
            $(this).text('about');
          }
    });
});
```

```css
nav{
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

nav ul{
  list-style-type: none;
}

nav ul li{
  display: inline-block;
}

nav ul li a{
  font-size: 40px;
  margin: 0 10px;
}

p{
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

div{
  width: 100%; 
  text-align: center;
}

.hide{
  display: none;
}
```

```html
   <nav>
      <ul>
        <li><a id="link_one" class="link" data-target="accreditations" href="#">link 1</a></li>
        <li><a id="link_two" href="#" class="link" data-target="our_prods">link 2</a></li>
        <li><a id="link_three" href="#" class="link" data-target="why_us">link 3</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
    
    <div class="pageContainer" id="about_us">
      <p>About Us Page - to be displayed by default</p>
    </div>
    
    <div class="pageContainer" id="accreditations">
      <p>Accreditations Page Content - Link 1</p>
    </div>
    
    <div class="pageContainer" id="our_prods">
      <p>Our products - Link 2</p>
    </div>
    
    <div class="pageContainer" id="why_us">
      <p>Why us content - link 3</p>
    </div>
    
    <script
      src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"
      integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4="
      crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: Preserve your link text in an attribute and previous clicked link as well in a variable. If your variable is empty that means it clicked first time and any value will help you to revert back the text.

Comment: Reece, sorry didn't see your question in the discussion yesterday - it never showed up.  Have answered it now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try the following - I have commented js to show what I am doing.  Only other changes are to links - use target ids as href and add hide class to page containers you do not want to display by default

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var links = $('.link'),
    containers = $('.pageContainer'); // cache these for better performance

  links.on('click', function(e) { // pass event into function
    var link = $(this);
    e.preventDefault(); // add this to stop the default action of the link 

    containers.addClass('hide');
    $(link.attr('href')).removeClass('hide'); // use the href so it is more accessible - ie link will work without js
    
    if (link.attr('href').substr(1) === link.data('target')) { // only do this if original href

      links.not(link).text(function() {
        return $(this).data('text'); // reset text
      }).attr('href', function() {
        return '#' + $(this).data('target'); // reset href
      });

      link.attr("href", "#about_us").text('about'); // not sure how you want to set the text and link for this 
                                                    // maybe use more data attributes so it can be different per link
    } else {
      // reset link if it was about that was clicked
      link.text(link.data('text')).attr('href', '#' + link.data('target')); // reset href and text
    }
  });
});
```

```css
nav {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

nav ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}

nav ul li {
  display: inline-block;
}

nav ul li a {
  font-size: 40px;
  margin: 0 10px;
}

p {
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

div {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a id="link_one" href="#accreditations" class="link" data-target="accreditations" data-text="link 1">link 1</a></li>
    <li><a id="link_two" href="#our_prods" class="link" data-target="our_prods" data-text="link 2">link 2</a></li>
    <li><a id="link_three" href="#why_us" class="link" data-target="why_us" data-text="link 3">link 3</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>

<div class="pageContainer" id="about_us">
  <p>About Us Page - to be displayed by default</p>
</div>

<div class="pageContainer hide" id="accreditations">
  <p>Accreditations Page Content - Link 1</p>
</div>

<div class="pageContainer hide" id="our_prods">
  <p>Our products - Link 2</p>
</div>

<div class="pageContainer hide" id="why_us">
  <p>Why us content - link 3</p>
</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted, its just gonna take me a while to understand exactly what is happening haha. Thanks

Comment: @Reece, just edited so it starts with about us section shown as default, then if you click back to about, it will show about again and revert link to normal

Comment: What does passing the event into the function do?

Comment: it allows you to stop the default action of the link - eg if the link were to go to a different page, it just stops that action so you stay on the same page: https://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/.  It also holds a lot of information about the click event - such as the clicked item, etc - if you do a console.log(event), you will see what data it holds - https://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144570/discussion-between-reece-and-pete).

Answer (score 0):

Save the prev text inside the link in a data attribute.Then on click reset all div 
 with initial text and then set the new text to the target div

For activaitng link on second click add a new class to the div on first click.Then change the href if that class doesnot exists

A sample demo attached

```js
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('.link').on('click', function() {
       $('.link').each(function( ){
            $(this).text($(this).data('inactive-text'));
       })
        $('.pageContainer').addClass('hide');
        $('#'+ $(this).data('target')).removeClass('hide');
        
        $(this).text( $(this).data('active-text') );
        
        if($(this).hasClass("clicked")){
           $(this).attr("href", "https://www.google.com");
        }
        $(this).addClass("clicked")
         
    });
});
```

```css
nav{
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

nav ul{
  list-style-type: none;
}

nav ul li{
  display: inline-block;
}

nav ul li a{
  font-size: 40px;
  margin: 0 10px;
}

p{
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

div{
  width: 100%; 
  text-align: center;
}

.hide{
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<nav>
      <ul>
        <li><a id="link_one" class="link" data-target="accreditations" href="#" data-inactive-text="link 1" data-active-text="about" >link 1</a></li>
        <li><a id="link_two" href="#" class="link" data-target="our_prods" data-inactive-text="link 2" data-active-text="about" >link 2</a></li>
        <li><a id="link_three" href="#" class="link" data-target="why_us"data-inactive-text="link 3"  data-active-text="about" >link 3</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
    
    <div class="pageContainer" id="about_us">
      <p>About Us Page - to be displayed by default</p>
    </div>
    
    <div class="pageContainer" id="accreditations">
      <p>Accreditations Page Content - Link 1</p>
    </div>
    
    <div class="pageContainer" id="our_prods">
      <p>Our products - Link 2</p>
    </div>
    
    <div class="pageContainer" id="why_us">
      <p>Why us content - link 3</p>
    </div>
    
    <script
      src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"
      integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4="
      crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `e.preventDefault()` to prevent the default behavior of the `<a/>` tag. that way it wont redirect to the link.
But you said you want it to redirect it on the second click, then you need a counter of some sort. one solution is to keep a `data-attribute` on the element itself and change it after the click.

for example:

```js
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('.link').on('click', function(e)
    {
        if($(this).attr('data-times-clicked') == '0'){
          e.preventDefault();
          $(this).attr('data-times-clicked', 1);
          $('.pageContainer').addClass('hide');
          $('#'+ $(this).data('target')).removeClass('hide');

          $(this).attr("href", "https://www.google.com");
          $(this).text('about');
        }
    });
});
```

```css
nav{
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

nav ul{
  list-style-type: none;
}

nav ul li{
  display: inline-block;
}

nav ul li a{
  font-size: 40px;
  margin: 0 10px;
}

p{
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

div{
  width: 100%; 
  text-align: center;
}

.hide{
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<nav>
      <ul>
        <li><a id="link_one" data-times-clicked="0" class="link" data-target="accreditations" href="#">link 1</a></li>
        <li><a id="link_two" data-times-clicked="0"  href="#" class="link" data-target="our_prods">link 2</a></li>
        <li><a id="link_three" data-times-clicked="0"  href="#" class="link" data-target="why_us">link 3</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
    
    <div class="pageContainer" id="about_us">
      <p>About Us Page - to be displayed by default</p>
    </div>
    
    <div class="pageContainer" id="accreditations">
      <p>Accreditations Page Content - Link 1</p>
    </div>
    
    <div class="pageContainer" id="our_prods">
      <p>Our products - Link 2</p>
    </div>
    
    <div class="pageContainer" id="why_us">
      <p>Why us content - link 3</p>
    </div>
    
    <script
      src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"
      integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4="
      crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

try Code : Jquery Changed

```js
     $(document).ready(function()
        {
            $('.link').on('click', function() {
               $('.link').each(function( ){
                    $(this).text($(this).data('inactive-text'));
               })
                $('.pageContainer').addClass('hide');
                $('#'+ $(this).data('target')).removeClass('hide');

                $(this).text( $(this).data('active-text') );

            });
        });
```

Html change Code:

```
    <!-- language: lang-html -->

        <nav>
              <ul>
                <li><a id="link_one" class="link" data-target="accreditations" href="#" data-inactive-text="link 1" data-active-text="about" >link 1</a></li>
                <li><a id="link_two" href="#" class="link" data-target="our_prods" data-inactive-text="link 2" data-active-text="about" >link 2</a></li>
                <li><a id="link_three" href="#" class="link" data-target="why_us"data-inactive-text="link 3"  data-active-text="about" >link 3</a></li>
              </ul>
            </nav>
```